# Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.Connect throwing SshConnectionException

Tags: c#, sftp, ssh.net

I'm working with the Renci.SshNet library (v2016.0.0) in a C# application, which is scheduled to upload a file to an FTP server on a daily basis. When testing on my machine the code behaves as expected uploading the file to the SFTP server. However, after deploying to production we are seeing the following exception, even though the application is connecting to the same SFTP host address:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification.
    at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
    at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

The corresponding code that is throwing the exception is as follows:

```
using (FileStream fileToUpload = new FileStream(exportFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(SftpHost, 22, SftpUserName, new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFileName)))
    {
        sftpClient.ErrorOccurred += SftpErrorHandler;

        sftpClient.Connect(); // Line throwing the exception

        if (!sftpClient.IsConnected)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"An error occurred while connecting to the SFTP server {SftpHost}");
        }

        sftpClient.UploadFile(fileToUpload, fileName);
        sftpClient.Disconnect();
        sftpClient.ErrorOccurred -= SftpErrorHandler;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this issue? From my perspective, this seems to be a very nondescript error. I'm wondering if this is a firewall configuration on the machine running the application? Or perhaps it's a configuration issue on the SFTP server that the application is connecting to?

Comment: First thing to try is to connect manually using any SSH/SFTP client from the production machine.